# Inserting an Image and Date into Db with Prepared Statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following query that I'm trying to convert to a prepared statement:

```
$NewPostQ = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO admin_panel(datetime, title, category, author, image, post) VALUES('$DateTime', '$Title', '$Category', '$Admin', '$Image', '$Post')");
```

Here is what I have:

```
$NewPostQ = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO admin_panel(datetime, title, category, author, image, post) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

$NewPostQ->bind_param("isssbs", $DateTime, $Title, $Category, $Admin, $Image, $Post);
$NewPostQ->execute();

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Image"]["tmp_name"], $Target);
```

Everything is going into the DB except the image and the datetime.  I have $Datetime as follows:

```
$CurrentTime = time();
$DateTime = strftime("%b-%d-%Y %H: %M: %S", $CurrentTime);
```

It's going into a varchar(50) in dB.   Image is as follows:

```
$Image = $_FILES["Image"]["name"];
$Target = "../assets/upload/".basename($_FILES["Image"]["name"]);
```

This is going into varchar(200) in dB.  My understanding was that dates were characterized as integers and images as blobs in `bind_param` so I set them as i and b  (`"isssbs"`).  Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working?  In datetime I get a zero and for image it's just empty.

Comment: As your doing strftime() on the time it will return a string.

Comment: yes it does.  I changed this to `s` and now this is fine thankyou.  Why is the image not bound as `b`?

Comment: weird, it's an `s` too.  Goes against everything I read but OK, it works!

Comment: `$Image` is the name of the image,not the contents.

Comment: Why do you have `"isssbs"`? Why not just `$NewPostQ->bind_param($DateTime, $Title, $Category, $Admin, $Image, $Post);`?

Comment: @JeanPaul98 b/c it tells the database what the parameters are, thereby minimizing the risk of SQL injection.